# Passing static path to included template

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to pass a static path as a variable to an included template?

I need to repeatedly include a template on my page but its always with different logos.

For example:

```
    {% with img={% static 'img/dashboards/belgium_flag.svg' %} %}
        {% include 'dashboards/charts/country_block.html' %}
    {% endwith %}

    {% with img={% static 'img/dashboards/netherlands_flag.svg' %} %}
        {% include 'dashboards/charts/country_block.html' %}
    {% endwith %}
```

This doesn't work..

Is there any workaround to this besides creating a model to support an image attribute to each Country instance?

Comment: I don't believe you can nest `{% %}` tags.  Try `with img='img/dashboards/belgium_flag.svg'`, and then handle the `{% static %}` tag inside the included template.  (Is there ever a case where the image path _wouldn't_ be in static?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `{% … as … %}` clause:

```
{% static 'img/dashboards/belgium_flag.svg' as img %}
{% include 'dashboards/charts/country_block.html' %}


{% static 'img/dashboards/netherlands_flag.svg' as img %}
{% include 'dashboards/charts/country_block.html' %}
```

Comment: You don't need a `with` ?

Comment: @JohnGordon: no, we here define a local variable `img` and set the value to that local variable.

Comment: Neat!  Didn't know you could do that.